# Django forms add a anchor tag in forms.py

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In django forms how to add a anchor tag in form class without customizing form.html

### forms.py

```
class HealthCheckerForm(PortalModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128,required = False ,help_text="Enter Name", label='Name')
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=128, required = False, label='desc*')

    age = forms.CharField(max_length=128,required = False ,help_text="Enter age", label='age')
    group = forms.CharField(max_length=128, required = False, label='group*')
```

### form.html

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        <div class="fieldInfo">
            {{ field.label_tag }}{{ field }}
            <span class="errorList">{{ field.errors|striptags}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

without customizing form.html how to add a button or an anchor tag

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You could take a look at crispy forms where you can customize the layout:https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms. You can add divs around your fields and also add html between fields.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood your question; it seems similar to the problem I came across today.

Basically you can create your own Widget and Field.

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class AnchorOnlyWidget(forms.Widget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs):
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, name=name)
        if hasattr(self, 'initial'):
            value = self.initial
        return mark_safe("<a href='%s' %s>%s</a>" %
            (value, flatatt(final_attrs), value))

    def _has_changed(self, initial, data):
        return False

class AnchorOnlyField(forms.FileField):
    widget = AnchorOnlyWidget
    def __init__(self, widget=None, label=None, initial=None, help_text=None):
        forms.Field.__init__(self, label=label, initial=initial,
            help_text=help_text, widget=widget)

    def clean(self, value, initial):
        self.widget.initial = initial
        return initial
```

And then add it to your form:

```
class HealthCheckerForm(PortalModelForm):
    youranchor = AnchorOnlyField(help_text="the help")
    ...
```